# Passing multiple arguments into python urllib module

Tags: python-3.x, urllib

I am having some issues passing multiple variables into the python urllib module.

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus as urlquote
PASS='test1'
FAIL='test2'
VAR1 = ('test1:%s' % (urlquote((PASS))))
#VAR2 = ('%s:%s' % (urlquote((FAIL,FAIL))))
print(VAR1)
#print(VAR2)
```

When i run the script as is with the `VAR2` variable commented out, i get the expected result with is

```
test:test1
```

Unfortunately when i run it with `VAR2` line uncommented, i get the error below

```
TypeError: quote_from_bytes() expected bytes
```

The expected result should be

```
test1:test1
test2:test2
```

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out

```
from urllib.parse import quote_plus as urlquote
PASS='test1'
FAIL='test2'
VAR1 = ('test1:%s' % (urlquote(PASS)))
VAR2 = ('%s:%s' % (urlquote(FAIL),urlquote(FAIL)))
print(VAR1)
print(VAR2)
```